# Keep checkbox checked in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Using angular 9 and some custom input I made the following =>

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rgsatp

I would like to prevent user from disabling a radio button that is currently checked, so I changed the following in `radio-button.component`

from

```
<label [class]="'radio-container ' + cssClass || ''">
  <div class="radio">
    {{ checked }}
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="checked" [(ngModel)]="checked" (click)="click()" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</label>
```

I remove the binding of ngModel to do `[ngModel]="checked"` and force the state on the input.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x2sszw

The problem I face i, although the check stay true, the css do not, and I do not understand why it's not forced to check.

Comment: Use ngclass directive. That should solve the issue.

Comment: yeah I went this way thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and uncheck are browser events, perhaps you should use `event.preventDefault()` to stop default behavior of browser

Like

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="checked" [ngModel]="checked" (click)="click($event)" />
```

And

```
click(event): void {
  if (this.checked) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  if (!this.disabled) {
    this.checked = true
    this.emitChange()
  }
}
```

Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pomkvy

Also I would like to add two more points

1. Don't add unnecessary variable like in your example `this.disabled`. Because Angular runs its cycle on every event. So it might affect performance
2. Use radio instead of checkbox, that would make it easier

Comment: my angular change detection is onpush, and I have a custom disable and using checbox because I need to thune how the inputs work (like angular material is doing), yeah is not the best, but it's to limiting to use native radio.

Thanks for the answer, I forgot to prevent default indeed

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<label [class]="'radio-container ' + cssClass || ''">
  <div class="radio">
    {{ checked }}
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="checked" [ngModel]="checked" (click)="click()" [attr.disabled]="checked ? true : null" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-ivy-rx2udp