# How to change the check status of a checkbox in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have my input below:

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [name]="myCheck">
```

I want to get the element in TypeScript file and change in it some sort of like:

```js
document.getElementByName("myCheck").checked = true;
```

But the 'checked' property is not recognizable.

So how should I proceed?

Comment: I didn't see any `id` attribute in your input field.

Comment: @HardikSolanki I updated the content of my question

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript

Comment: getElementByName doesn't exist - use an ID instead as @HardikSolanki mentioned

Comment: @BernardBorg getElementByName()  function exists !

Comment: It does not. It's getElementsByName(). Note the s after Element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep checkbox checked in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62891765/keep-checkbox-checked-in-angular)

Comment: with vanilla js you will not be able to access angular input -> an angular way to do this is to use viewChild

Comment: You have not an angular valid html. This code give you error. You should understand a minimum about Angular, binding and interpolation. BTW all the responses looks like not try make a [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes), not understand nothing. I know that it's about four hours but sincerily all of you stole me the force to answer.

Comment: this is cause by a typo. either you're using angular wrong or html wrong. The name of the element is specified either by using `name="myCheck"` or in Angular `[name]="'myCheck'"`. In your case you're setting the name of the element to the value of component property `myCheck` which might be null or undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `getElementByName`, but that's not a valid function. It should be `getElementsByName` and then give a valid index.

You can also use `querySelector("[name='myCheck']")`.

As for typescript:

You first have to let typescript know what the element exactly is:

```
const checkboxEl = document.getElementsByName("myCheck")[0] as HTMLInputElement;
checkboxEl.checked = true;
```

Comment: "HtmlInputCheckBox" class do not exist

Comment: why not use `[(ngModel)]`? Angular is **not** javascript. Angular is simply declare variables in .ts that you use as [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) or [binding](https://angular.io/guide/binding-overview) in your .html.

Answer (score -1):

getElementsByName return the collection either use the ID or access the first element

```
 document.getElementsByName("myCheck")[0].checked = true;
```

Comment: Same error, 'checked' property not recognizable.

Comment: could you share the stackblitz  or jsfiddle link of your code

Comment: When I try using the ID, I get the error below :

TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'HTMLElement'.   Property '0' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: share the code or error screenshot